# Error "Array to string conversion in .." in SQLSRV order by clause

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, sqlsrv

why i always get this error :

```
Array to string conversion in ..
```

every time i use ORDER BY clause in PHP - SQLSRV. 
( i am abit new to SQLSRV so please edit my question if you think it's necessary)

even simple query such as

```
SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY fieldA ASC
```

cause that error too.

if i remove the 'order by', everything works fine.
below is my php sqlsrv script:

```
$conn = "some db setting";

$query= "(SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY fieldA ASC)";

$queryparams = array("");

$querun = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query, $queryparams);
```

version i use :

```
php 5.4.31

SQL Server 2008
```

edit for more info:
the query works fine if i run directly from SQL STUDIO

Comment: You are setting $queryparams to an array containing one empty string. I think you are intending to set it to an empty string, that would be: $queryparams = array();

Comment: hi Majiy,.i think that's not the case, since if i delete the 'order by', the query works fine and shows  result .

Comment: did you try removing the `$queryparams` ? I think the error is produce because 1st you are not setting what does the `$queryparams` is for. the query be should be like "SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE (?) = (?) ORDER BY fieldA ASC" and the `$queryparams` maybe like array('name', 'unknown')

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets / parentheses from your query string so it's:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY fieldA ASC";
```

Having the brackets / parentheses in your query string causes a Syntax Error in SQL. Your query returns `false` with an array containing the error message like the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 156 [code] => 156 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'. ) )
```

I'm guessing you are trying to echo out  an array, hence the `Array to String conversion` message.

Comment: hi ImClarky, actually i am putting that $queryparams  just in case when i want to use parameter inside the sql in the future. but at as for now, i wont be  using any parameter in the sql so i leave the array blank. tried to remove the bracket also but the error stil the same "Array to string conversion in"

Comment: @psaka how are you retrieving the data?

Comment: Also having an empty parameters array is perfectly fine - as long as the query isn't expecting any of course... I never said it was a problem. It's just  the brackets `()` in your `$query` string that's an issue. And then also how you are retrieving your data.

Comment: its about something like this : while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryrun)) {
 $somevalue1 = $row['somevalue1'];
 $somevalue2 = $row['somevalue2'];
 echo $somevalue1;
}  .. thou what i found quite funny is, this "order by" php-sql thingy  work fine when i do it in the other sql server which is using mssql, not sqlsrv.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the responses,
i just want to share my finding regarding my own issues :/

it seems that if we put the ORDER BY as the sub query, the query works fine. something like this :

```
SELECT *  FROM (
SELECT a,b,c,d,e FROM tableA ORDER BY fieldA ASC
) X
```

i dont know wether this is a proper answer or not , but this tricky solution helps me. 
i am still open for more info/answer thou :)